# Using keyvalue pipe when iterate form controls

Tags: angular

I'm using keyvalue pipe when iterate angular form controls.

The problem is that I'm getting error on "ngIf" that "disabled" in not exists in key value and it's obvious because only key\value are exists.

Any solution?

```
<form [formGroup]="facilitiesForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="newDists">
   <div
   class="facility-form"
   *ngFor="let dist of newDists.controls; let i = index"
    >
  {{ currentData[i].name }}
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <div formArrayName="methods">
      <div *ngFor="let item of getMethods(i).controls; let x = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="x">
            <div *ngFor="let ctrl of item.value | keyvalue">
            Key: <b>{{ctrl.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{ctrl.value}}</b>
            <input *ngIf="!ctrl.disabled" type="text" formControlName="{{ctrl.key}}">
            
            &nbsp;<button (click)="editMethod(ctrl)" type="button">Edit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Aren't you just missing the `.value`? `!ctrl.value.disabled`.

Comment: `item.value` give you the value of the form control assuming item is a `FormControl`.  If you want to see if the `FormControl` is disabled via the form control's `disabled` property you should be checking `*ngIf="item.disabled"`

Comment: I changed the control to "ctrl" and when trying to hide it by *ngIf="!ctrl.disabled" im getting the error:
 Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'KeyValue<unknown, unknown>'

Comment: Yes, as Jason suggested `*ngIf="item.disabled"` it should work. Did you gave try @eladr?

Comment: Because of the keyvalue pipe, shouldn't it be ctrl.value.disabled?